# What's the difference between まで and までに?

Tags: word-choice, particle-まで

I'm studying for N3 Japanese test. I'm stuck in a sentence of an exercise in which is written

> 帰国{きこく}するまでになんとか日本語{にほんご}を習得{しゅうとく}したい。

Why is it wrong to say

> 帰国するまでなんとか日本語を習得したい。?

I really don't get it, if someone could teach me the difference I would be really happy. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1150/7810

Answer (score 14):

In short,

- まで = *until*
- までに = *by*

Or to say, `A まで B` means *B* keeps taking place while *A* doesn't come, and `A までに B` means *B* gets to come true before (the end of) *A* comes. Thus,

> 帰国するまでなんとか日本語を習得したい。

would (even we overlook some stiffness) imply you're willing to forget Japanese after you return, which is not a very laudable attitude for a Japanese student :D