# Difference between に and まで?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-まで

What's the difference between the particles に、and まで? And what does it mean when combined to make までに?

I've been quite confused as to what these two mean. And I was hoping someone could compare the two to help me understand.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of 2 questions: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40823/9749  and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/275/9749

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I guess it would be good to plainly lay out what the two mean.

に can be used to mean "to (a destination)", the precise time of an even (３時**に**　**at** 3 o'clock) attached to a verb in stem form to mean "to do that thing (見**に**行った went (there) **to** watch (it)) as well as some other cases.

So, it's something like "to" or "at" or "in" etc.

まで is a little simpler. It basically means "until". Whether it's talking about *until* a certain time, or *until* a certain state.

When they are combined I believe in most situations it is just that they are  being attached to the same word at the same time.

その日**までに**提出してください。
Please submit it **by** that day.

It's like saying "up to and on that day", or maybe "up to and including".

In this case, it just so happens we can translate it as one word, "by".

This can be done with other particles too. では　には　にも　かも　までも etc.

These can also often be translated as a single word.

In some cases, the second particle makes the first unnecessary so it gets deleted essentially.  You wouldn't say 私がも just 私も for example.

Comment: I didn't actually know the 見に行った thing... cool!