# Sleeping verbs and まで vs までに

Tags: verbs, history, aspect, linguistics, particle-まで

So I was wondering, pretty much all of the sleep related verbs switch meaning with まで and までに.

Was it always like that? Or was there a time when ８時まで寝る meant "going to bed at 8"?

Or take the even more obvious 寝入る, same story. ８時まで寝入る *shouldn't* mean getting up at 8.

Just curious where that original meaning went or if it was always like that.

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ab/40826#40826

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between まで and までに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ab) 8時まで寝る always means waking up at 8.

Comment: I know the difference, my question is *why*?